# Delete a row in a table in Dreamweaver

Tags: row, dreamweaver

How can I create a button that will delete a table entry in Dreamweaver? I have tried to use the delete a record in a Dreamweaver but it didn't work for me.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please, post what have you tried so far and which issues you've found on your way.

Comment: Is this a real question?

Answer (score 0):

It would be easy for us to see what have you done so far so that we can help. Try to check if the value of primary key has pass while you click delete button.

Comment: Done! I checked it in the url of the redirecting page.. Thank you... I had just to much what is being sent with what is being received :)